# Почему данные приходят не так, как ожидается?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-hook

Имеется такой React Component

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

//UI

import PokemonItem from './../PokemonItem';

function PokemonList() {

    const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState({
        pokemonList: null,
        loading: true,
    }); 

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(body => {
            setPokemons({
                pokemonList: body.results,
                loading: false,
            })

        })
    }, [])

    console.log(pokemons); 

    return(
        <div className="pokemon-list">
        </div>
    )
}

export default PokemonList;
```

После вызова хука `useEffect()`, я смотрю в консоли, что у меня находится в `pokemons` (В переменной, в которую должны были придти данные)

Но почему-то в консоли появляется 2 лога, один с начальными данными, а потом с уже пришедшими данными, почему так происходит?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта проблема в дальнейшем не позволяет мне работать с данными, видимо происходит какая-то ошибка, что я делаю не правильно?

Пытался добавить эту строку `console.log(pokemons);`  после `setPokemons();`, в таком случаи в консоли появляется один лог с начальными данными, т.е. null в `pokemonList`, данные еще не успевают придти.

Comment: смотри  у тебя консоль лог   выводится при каждом ререндере компонента . первый   раз у тебя выводится после mount .   второй раз -  когда  прходит ответ от сервера.  и записался setPockemons.  напиши что конкретно тебе нужно.. и чем эта проблема тебе не позволяет двигаться дальше))

Answer (score 1):

как правильно сказал Сергей

```
useEffect(() => {}, [])
```

срабатывает после первого рендера компоненты. Это эквивалентно `componentDidMount` в классовых компонентах.

соответственно вы видете 2 разных состояния - начальное и когда пришел ответ от сервера и поменялся `state` компоненты

предположу что ваша проблема связана с тем что вы делаете map для pokemons.pokemonList и ваше начальное значение это null.

самый простой способ решения этой проблемы инициализировать начальное состояние как

```
const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState({
    pokemonList: [],
    loading: true,
});
```

Comment: Да, действительно, оно так и есть, я не могу использовать map, это лучшая практика по решению данной проблемы? Или есть более элегантное решение?

Comment: решений много. лучше конечно всегда в переменной иметь один тип данных. у вас есть ключ loading, если он true, можно в return возвращать например лоадер. это как пример:)

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi Просто добавьте ещё один ретурн или условие мэпа. if(pokemons.loading === true) return null